# Similarity of two terms contain spelling mistakes

Tags: python, vectorization, spell-checking, similarity, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to determine the similarity between two terms; one that is spelt correctly, and the other that may or may not contain a spelling mistake(s).

To do this right now I am vectorizing both terms using a TFIDFvectorizer, then using a similarity method to determine the similarity between them.

This works for the following type of examples:

```
Original term  | Input term  |  Similarity
---------------------------------------
red car        | red car     |  1.0
red car        | big red car |  0.75
```

However, if there is a spelling mistake such as:

```
Original term  | Input term  |  Similarity
------------------------------------------
red car        | redd carr   |  0.0
```

It gives a similarity of `0`, even though they are somewhat similar terms (I'm not excepting to get a similarity of `1.0`, but aiming to get a similarity > `0.0`.

One consideration I had was to break down each word into X characters, so that each term would be:

`Original term = ['re', 'ed', 'd ', ' c', 'ca', 'ar']`

`Input term = ['re', 'ed', 'dd', 'd ', ' c', 'ca', 'ar', 'rr']`

Then determine the similarity of these against eachother and calculate the average similarity.

I would really appreciate any other suggestions for potential approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) anu use to you? 
I think it may be geared towards longer sequences.

```
In[1]: import difflib
In[5]: mr = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
In[7]: mr.set_seqs('red car', 'redd carr') 
In[8]: mr.ratio()
Out[8]: 0.875
In[9]: mr.set_seqs('red car', 'redd ship') 
In[10]: mr.ratio()
Out[10]: 0.5
```

Comment: Sorry if my answer is naive, Isee you are asking about TFIDFVECTORIZER which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check the following link where it shows you   [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

For tf-idf purposes, you might also be interested in just getting the root of the words. The `nltk` library, specifically the `stem()` part (check the following [link](https://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html)), could help you through that process. However, if your problem is just on these particular words, you could just create a replacement function for this spelling mistakes and passing it before using tf-idf.